# Get PID of scheduled job (using at)?

Tags: process, scheduling, at

Say I want to schedule this job to be run at later time

```
MYPROGRAM > output.out 2> error.err | at 02:00 PM Mon
```

How can I attain its PID? Surely using:

```
echo $!
```

will not work?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? You can't get the pid until the program runs, is `MYPROGRAM` trying to get its own pid for some purpose? (And is it a shell script, otherwise, `$!` won't mean anything to it?)

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a PID of a process which is not currently running, so there is no meaning for PID of a scheduled job.